# how do i get value from a button dropdown and save it in localStorage? Angular 4

Tags: angular, local-storage, dropdown

I have a button dropdown

```
<div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle form-group" (click)="get()" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span id="selected">View Domains</span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu arrow form-group">
              <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="1">1</button>
              <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="2">2</button>
              <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="3">3</button>
            </div>
    </div>



 $('.dropdown-menu button').click(function(){
      $('#selected').text($(this).text());
    });
```

I want to get the value of dropdown in the component when they select any options (1,2,3) for eg: if they select 1, I should be able to get the value=1 in the component, and save it to localStorage.

Comment: Are you using jquery for that dropdown-menu?

Comment: It looks like you're using bootstrap 4. If so use ng-bootsrap.  It'll make your life a lot easier.

Comment: yes I edited the question with click function @Andrew

Comment: @yer drop jquery and use angular! or as someone else said, use ng-bootstrap. It already comes with angular directives for what jquery was doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your ts file

```
myText = 'View Domains'

select(val){
    this.myText = val;
    localStorage.setItem('myText', this.myText);
}
```

in your template

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle form-group" (click)="get()" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span id="selected">{{myText}}</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu arrow form-group">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="1" (click)="select(1)">1</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="2" (click)="select(2)">2</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="3" (click)="select(3)">3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `click` event on `<div class="dropdown-menu arrow form-group">`, Update the HTML as below.

`<div class="dropdown-menu arrow form-group" (click)="onSelect($event)">`

Then in component add `onSelect` method as below.

`onSelect(event) {
  localStorage.setItem("selectedItem", event.target.value);
  // Do the rest
}`

Comment: How do I get the "value"?

Comment: @yer, sorry I missed out "event.target",
You can get the value by using: `event.target.value`